# Commit and prove

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

Is it possible to commit to a value $s$ and then prove in NIZK way that $g = q^s$ ?

Both $g,q$ are known.  Thank you.

Comment: If you're commiting to $s$ I imagine you'll open it later. When does that happen? And if you're opening $s$ then why do you need a proof?

Comment: I will only open s in case of disputes and that  will reset the protocol.

Comment: Right, perhaps you need a proof for the statement $Commit(s) = c \wedge g = q^s$ and release $(c, g)$, which is your instance. This can be done generically but I'm not sure how to do it algebraically.

Comment: Is there a reason that the relationship $g=q^s$ itself doesn't work as a commitment?  It is certainly both binding and hiding...

Comment: Assuming $g=q^s$ is used as commitment.  How can I prove $w=k^s$ in NIZK?  I need to prove $s=dlog_q g= dlog_k w$.

Comment: @poncho I believe the hiding definition is like the indistinguishably definition so the adversary can easily distinguish if he can pick the message $s$.

Comment: @lamba: actually, in this case, if the attacker knew the value of $s$ s.t. $g = q^s$, then the hiding property of the commitment is irrelevant (because the attacker would already know the committed value).  Hence, we can assume that the attacker doesn't know $s$ (and can't compute it based on that one relation)